# Maintain div proportions and positions

Tags: css

This might be simple but I'm having difficulties getting this right.

I want to be able to maintain the proportions and positions of multiple center aligned DIVs while resizing. Like in a fluid layout.

This is a example jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qp6pubtv/. I want to maintain this in  a fluid environment.

[image]

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="outouter">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middleA"></div>
            <div class="middleB"></div>
            <div class="middleC"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outouter{
    background-color: GreenYellow;
    width:300px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
}
.outer{
    background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
    width:90%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.middleA{
    background-color: CadetBlue;
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.middleB{
    background-color: DarkGoldenRod;
    width:70%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.middleC{
    background-color: DarkOrchid;
    width:60%;
    height: 60%;
    position: absolute;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Include your code please.

Comment: @hungerstar: thanks. I just updated. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qp6pubtv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `left` and `right` properties into each inner block, i.e.

```
.middleA{
    background-color: CadetBlue;
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /*this*/
    right: 0; /*this*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qp6pubtv/1/ (I also made the parent 100% width and height)

Comment: Doesn't work when the parent has a fixed width and height `width:300px; height: 250px;`?

Comment: it will work on any size. I made it full size because you said "fluid".

Answer (score 0):

You need set width for wrapper div width in % or em it gonna main, for each step inner need set dimension relative outer in %. On resize width would be changed.

Comment: For absolute you need set position: relative for element withch contain square. Without be problem.

Comment: sorry I'm not following you. All are squares?

Comment: Set for main <div> that contains you .outouter position: relative